# Доступ к элементам вектора указателей

Tags: c++

```
  vector<int*> v;
  int p = 1;
  v.push_back(&p);
  //cout << что-то; //Здесь должно выводиться p(то есть, 1)
```

Comment: `*v.front()`, `*v[0]`, `*v.at(0)`. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: @kff в моем слабоумии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала нужно выудить элемент из массива. Например, так

```
p[0];
```

Это будет указатель на `int`. Теперь нужно "содрать звездочку" - разименовать

```
*p[0];
```

Теперь можно выводить

```
cout << *p[0];
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/DkxqyT)

**ВАЖНАЯ ПРОБЛЕМА**

Вы помещаете в массив указатель на переменную, которая существует на стеке. Если вы массив сохраните, а переменная пропадет из области видимости, получите *неопределенное поведение* при обращении к указателю.